# Calling VB6 method from C# from dynamic object with ByRef and optional Parameters

Tags: c#, dynamic, vb6, activator, createinstance

I usually make calls to class methods dynamically without problems, but only this method not works, always return error:

```
Dynamic conn = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyTeam.MyClass"));
bool test = false;
conn.MyFunction(100,"test",DateTime.Now, test, test, "another","another","another");
```

Original Method of external class with VB:

```
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal Id As Integer, ByVal Var1 As String, ByVal Fecha As Date, 
                                   Optional ByRef Opcion1 As Boolean = False, 
                                   Optional ByRef Opcion2 As Boolean = False, 
                                   Optional ByVal Var1 As String = "", 
                                   Optional ByVal Var2 As String = "",
                                   Optional ByVal Var3 As String = "" ) As String
```

- Question 1: Is it possible to omit optional parameters?
- Question 2: Is it possible call with ByRef parameters in other way?

UPDATE 1: Yes, C# supports ref/out parameters, but... variables of type "dynamic" calling Method, support this type of input?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Include the error in your question so we know what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# 4.0 optional out/ref arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870544/c-sharp-4-0-optional-out-ref-arguments)

Comment: Of course, C# supports this type of parameters, but not with "dynamic" objects? Function return "arguments not valid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass byref in c# you need to precede the parameter with `ref` when you *call* the function too.

```
conn.MyFunction(100,"test",DateTime.Now, ref test, ref test, "another","another","another");
```

Comment: C# works seamlessly with references, the DYNAMIC object encapsulates the complexity of translating these references. **The problem was the VB6 method itself**!!! solved.