# Converting VB.NET's DateTime.TryParse(string, Nothing) to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, parsing, datetime

I am currently trying to convert some vb into c# and in the vb code I have the following line:

```
If DateTime.TryParse(txtExpirationDate.Text, Nothing) = False Then 
_isValid = False
```

Which, with my extremely limited knowledge of vb, I think should read in c# as:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtExpirationDate.Text, null) == false)
        _isValid = false;
```

However visual studio is telling me that I have invalid arguments:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.TryParse(string, out System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments

I was wondering if anyone would be willing to help me out. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible in c# and if so how would I do it?

Comment: Check [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx). It'll help you.

Comment: I had already and it was little to no help to me. The documentation is the first place I look when I run into troubles. But thank you for the suggestion, your contribution is appreciated 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB allows you to use either a variable or an arbitrary expression as an `out`/`ref` argument. In the latter case, the returned value is ignored. C#, on the other hand, **requires a variable** to which the returned value can be written.

Before C# 7, [there's no way to ignore an `out` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/462167/87698). Thus, you need to declare a variable for this purpose (even if you don't use its value):

```
DateTime expirationDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtExpirationDate.Text, out expirationDate) == false)
    _isValid = false;
```

Comment: Thank you @Heinzi, I knew I was missing something silly. You have saved the day :)